# Getting Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid UTF-8 character "\xE3" in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets

I'm able to compile assets successfully through the development environment by the following command:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=development
```

However, when I compile the same set of assets through production environment, it throws the following error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid UTF-8 character "\xE3"
```

I do have a file where there is some Japanese written like this:

```
content: "必須";
```

I have commented this thing out, but it doesn't make any difference.

What I have tried:

I have put `@charset "UTF-8";` at the very top of each file, but still I'm getting the same error. I have also used `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile` with `=` sign instead of `+=` on multiple lines according to a Stackoverflow question, but it didn't help either.

I'm using Rails 5.0, and ruby 2.2.3.

For assets, I'm using the following gems:

```
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `LANG` & `LC_LANG` environment variables to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` will prevent this error:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

https://github.com/csswizardry/inuit.css/issues/270#issuecomment-56056606

Comment: It's already there in `~/bash_profile`, but it isn't helping.